# How to get the request parameter in a Session Bean (EJB)?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, ejb

My button in a HTML page is:

```
<a id="showTrail" href="/resources/showTrail?roy=show" target="iframe_a">
  <button>Show Trail</button>
</a>
```

My Java web service is:

```
package webServices;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;

/**
 * REST Web Service
 *
 * @author mkuchtiak
 */

@Stateless
@Path("/showTrail")
public class ShowTrail{

    @EJB
    private NameStorageBean nameStorage;

    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String getXml() {
        //String abc = request.getParameter("roy");
        return "<html><body><h1>Hello "+nameStorage.getName()+"!</h1></body></html>";
    }

    @PUT
    @Consumes("text/plain")
    public void putXml(String content) {
        nameStorage.setName(content);
    }

}
```

How I can get a request parameter from the HTML?
Will the following line work?

```
String abc = request.getParameter("roy");
```

I want to send an `HttpRequest` as parameter to send more parameters then "roy"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [@QueryParam](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html) annotation. That way you don't need to fiddle with `request.getParameter()` yourself.

**Java code**

```
@GET
@Produces("text/html")
public String getXml(@QueryParam("roy") String roy, 
                     @QueryParam("someInt") int someInt,
                     @QueryParam("orderBy") List<String> orderBy) {
```

**HTML**

```
<a id="showTrail" href="/resources/showTrail?roy=show&someInt=4711&orderBy=age&orderBy=name" target="iframe_a">
  <button>Show Trail</button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

append more variables like

```
href="/resources/showTrail?roy=show&var1=value1&var2=value3
```